# AWS Cognito hooks from SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

In depending on the user (from which provider coming and some another custom filed) I want to create different email templates for register/forgot password/change password/...

I know that is possible with AWS Lambda hooks in the AWS Cognito, but it is not a good solution in my case, because I have a lot of different templates.

Is it possible somehow to call some "hooks" or define that logic without Lambda?

Comment: Why is a lambda function not a good solution?

Comment: Because I will have hundreds and hundreds "if" statements in the lambda function code for detecting from where user coming and templates will be stored there, what is not a good solution. If you know how can I use resource from external, it is something different :)

Comment: There is no other way to add external triggers in a Cognito Authentication logic other than a Lambda trigger(in your case, the message customization Lambda Trigger). Depending on your use-case, you could look at the CUSTOM_AUTH flow though.

Comment: @Kolesar Well, you have to have this logic somewhere and Lambda seems to be a good place. If you don't want to bundle the templates in your Lambda just put them on S3 and fetch them according your needs.

Comment: Create your business logic as a http service, AWS Lambda hooks will "hook" your service by a http request.